# Convert all value in a array of object to string?

Tags: javascript

Convert all values of array of objects to string

```
 var a1 = [
      {
        conditionalFrom: 0,
        conditionalTo: 10000,
        computationFrom: 0,
        computationTo: 1000,
        value: '10'
      },
      {
        conditionalFrom: 10001,
        conditionalTo: 10000000,
        computationFrom: 1001,
        computationTo: 100000,
        value: '10'
      },
      {
        conditionalFrom: 10001,
        conditionalTo: 999999999999,
        computationFrom: 0,
        computationTo: 1000,
        value: '10'
      }
    ];
```

expected output

```
var a1 = [
          {
            conditionalFrom: "0",
            conditionalTo: "10000",
            computationFrom: "0",
            computationTo: "1000",
            value: "10"
          },
          {
            conditionalFrom: "10001",
            conditionalTo: "10000000"
            computationFrom: "1001",
            computationTo: "100000",
            value: "10"
          },
          {
            conditionalFrom: "10001",
            conditionalTo: "999999999999",
            computationFrom: "0",
            computationTo: "1000",
            value: "10"
          }
        ];



 const stringify = compactedSlabDetails.map(el => Object.keys(el).forEach(k => JSON.stringify(el[k])));
```

Comment: There's no need to use `JSON.stringify` here. Also `forEach` doesn't return anything, so the map would return `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map the entries to a new object and call `String` on the value in the entry.

```js
 var a1 = [
      {
        conditionalFrom: 0,
        conditionalTo: 10000,
        computationFrom: 0,
        computationTo: 1000,
        value: '10'
      },
      {
        conditionalFrom: 10001,
        conditionalTo: 10000000,
        computationFrom: 1001,
        computationTo: 100000,
        value: '10'
      },
      {
        conditionalFrom: 10001,
        conditionalTo: 999999999999,
        computationFrom: 0,
        computationTo: 1000,
        value: '10'
      }
    ];
const result = a1.map(
  obj => Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj)
      .map(([key, val]) => [key, String(val)])
  )
);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the key-value pairs to entries, map the values to strings, and then convert the entries back into an object.

```js
const original = [{
  conditionalFrom: 0,
  conditionalTo: 10000,
  computationFrom: 0,
  computationTo: 1000,
  value: '10'
}, {
  conditionalFrom: 10001,
  conditionalTo: 10000000,
  computationFrom: 1001,
  computationTo: 100000,
  value: '10'
}, {
  conditionalFrom: 10001,
  conditionalTo: 999999999999,
  computationFrom: 0,
  computationTo: 1000,
  value: '10'
}];

const modified = original.map(obj =>
  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => [key, `${value}`])));

console.log(modified);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```